# Reading a large XML file and parsing necessary elements into MySQLdb

Tags: python, parsing, xml, python-2.x, io

I have fair concept in a programming (learner) but not an expert to refactor code at the highest level. I am trying to read a huge (100MB-2GB) XML file and parse necessary element (attributes) from a file into MySQLdb. The code is working perfectly as I have tested in small file sizes. But, unfortunately when I got big size today (400MB-900MB), it's taking unexpected time.

Currently, I am diving into List Comprehension, `generator()`, `lambda()` and list reduction techniques.

Not to make more lines of code, but I have eliminated 3 or 4 elements from my list (taglist) from here. But, the structure of the code for rest of the eliminated elements are the same.

I am using: Python 2.7, lxml, MySQL (1.2.3)

```
import os, sys
import stat
import getpass
import MySQLdb
from lxml import etree
import datetime, time
import dbconfig as config

# All global variables set
 #Namespace which is default in every mzML file
#taglist=['mzML','sourceFile','software','dataProcessing','instrumentConfiguration','selectedIon']
taglist=['mzML','sourceFile']
NS="{http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml}"

def fast_iter(context, func,args=[],kwargs={}):
    # fast_iter is useful if we need to free memory while iterating through a
    # very large XML file.
    #http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
    # Author: Liza Daly

    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem,*args, **kwargs)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def process_element(elt):
    # global mzml_pk, sf_cv_fk,softw_fk_ID, softw_cv_fk_ID
    # Processing first element (mzML) and it's attributes (id, version, accession)
    # version attribute is required AND id & accession are optional
    if elt.tag==NS+taglist[0]:

        L= elt.keys()
        L1=['id','version','accession']

        # Checking whether element attributes (items L1) exist in a mzml element attributes (L)
        if L1[0] in L:
            mzmlID = elt.attrib['id']
        else:
            mzmlID = "-"
        if L1[1] in L:
            mzml_version = elt.attrib['version']
        else:
            mzml_version = "-"
        if L1[2] in L:
            mzml_accession = elt.attrib['accession']
        else:
            mzml_accession = "-"

        exp_id_fk = exp_PK

        sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_mzml (mzml_id,accession,version,exp_id)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        try:
            # Execute the SQL command
            config.cursor.execute(sql,(mzmlID,mzml_accession,mzml_version,exp_id_fk))
            # Commit your changes in the database
            config.conn.commit()

            #mzml_pk= cursor.lastrowid
        except Exception as err:
            # logger.error(err)
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            config.conn.rollback()
        global mzml_pk
        mzml_pk = config.cursor.lastrowid
    # Processing second element (sourceFile) which has attributes (id, name and location)
    # SourceFile attributes id, name and location are required
    # Further, sourceFile has child element (cvParam) and attributes (cvRef, name, accession, value)
    # cvParam attributes: cvRef, name, accession are Required and value optional

    elif elt.tag==NS+taglist[1]:
        sf_keys = elt.keys()
        sf_need = ['id','name','location']
        if sf_need[0] in sf_keys:
            sf_id = elt.attrib['id']
        else:
            sf_id, "-"
        if sf_need[1] in sf_keys:
            sf_name = elt.attrib['name']
        else:
           sf_name, "-"
        if sf_need[2] in sf_keys:
            sf_location = elt.attrib['location']
        else:
            sf_location = "-"
        global sf_fk
        sf_fk = mzml_pk
        #print "Insert values into django sourceFile class data model"

        sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_source_file (sf_id,name,location,mzml_fk_id)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        try:
            # Execute the SQL command
            config.cursor.execute(sql,(sf_id,sf_name,sf_location,sf_fk))
            # Commit your changes in the database
            config.conn.commit()

        except Exception as err:
            # logger.error(err)
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            config.conn.rollback()
        #sf_pk = cursor.lastrowid
        global sf_cv_fk
        sf_cv_fk= config.cursor.lastrowid

        for child in elt.getchildren():
            sf_child_keys =child.keys()
            sf_child_need = ['cvRef','name','accession','value']

            if sf_child_need[0] in sf_child_keys:
                sf_cv_cvref = child.attrib['cvRef']
            else:
                sf_cv_cvref = "-"
            if sf_child_need[1] in sf_child_keys:
                sf_cv_name = child.attrib['name']
            else:
                sf_cv_name = "-"
            if sf_child_need[2] in sf_child_keys:
                sf_cv_accession = child.attrib['accession']
            else:
                sf_cv_accession = "-"
            if sf_child_need[3] in sf_child_keys :
                if len(child.get('value'))>0:
                    sf_cv_value =  child.attrib['value']
                else:
                    sf_cv_value = "-"
            else:
                sf_cv_value = "-"

            sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_source_file_cv (ref, accession,name,value,sf_fk_id)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
            try:
                # Execute the SQL command
                config.cursor.execute(sql,(sf_cv_cvref,sf_cv_accession,sf_cv_name,sf_cv_value,sf_cv_fk))
                # Commit your changes in the database
                config.conn.commit()
            except Exception as err:
                # logger.error(err)
                # Rollback in case there is any error
                config.conn.rollback()
```

I haven't pasted the rest of the code for other elements because it's more than 300 lines, but of the same concept.

```
def convert_bytes(bytes):
    bytes = float(bytes)
    if bytes >= 1099511627776:
        terabytes = bytes / 1099511627776
        size = '%.2fTB' % terabytes
    elif bytes >= 1073741824:
        gigabytes = bytes / 1073741824
        size = '%.2fGB' % gigabytes
    elif bytes >= 1048576:
        megabytes = bytes / 1048576
        size = '%.2fMB' % megabytes
    elif bytes >= 1024:
        kilobytes = bytes / 1024
        size = '%.2fKB' % kilobytes
    else:
        size = '%.2fb' % bytes
    return size


def main():
    global EXP_PK
    # Start time counter
    begin=time.clock()

    # Reading file from the configured directory
    file_dir = r'D:\files\111102_CA2.mzML'

    # Reactor so it will read all new files from configured directory
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_dir)

    # File name and extension
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    user= getpass.getuser()
    exp_name = name
    exp_type= ext[1:]
    exp_created_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(os.path.getctime(file_dir)))
    exp_modi_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(file_dir)))
    exp_uploaddate= datetime.date.today()
    exp_uptime = str(datetime.datetime.now())[10:19]
    exp_size = convert_bytes(os.path.getsize(file_dir))
    #exp_located = r'C:\Users\Thaman\Documents\My Dropbox\Files\small1.mzML'
    exp_located = r'C:\My Documents\Dropbox\Files\plgs_example.mzML'
    #exp_located =r'D:\files\111102_CA2.mzML'

    sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_experiment (user,filename,filetype,createddate,modifieddate,uploaddate,time,size,located)
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        config.cursor.execute(sql,(user,exp_name,exp_type,exp_created_time,exp_modi_time,exp_uploaddate,exp_uptime,exp_size,exp_located))
        # Commit your changes in the database
        config.conn.commit()
    except:
        #logger.error(err)
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        config.conn.rollback()
    global exp_PK
    exp_PK = config.cursor.lastrowid
    #Reading elements from file
    for intag in range(len(taglist)):
        context= etree.iterparse(file_dir,events=("end",),tag=NS+taglist[intag])
        fast_iter(context, process_element)

    tend= time.clock()
    print "\n\nTIME TAKEN TO COMPLETE JOB", tend-begin

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Problem according to me:**

- I am sure my approach towards using too much `if` and `for` expression is a problem but haven't figure out the solution.
- 400 MB file is still and taking more than 1 hr.

**Reviewing:** Pythonic, memory friendly, speed optimization, structure

If someone wants the file, I can share it on Dropbox.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os, sys
import stat
import getpass
import MySQLdb
from lxml import etree
import datetime, time
import dbconfig as config
```

They python style guide recommends one import per line. I'd also probably group things together i.e. standard library imports then 3rd party imports/ then app imports. But that doesn't really matter much

```
# All global variables set
 #Namespace which is default in every mzML file

taglist=['mzML','sourceFile']
NS="{http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml}"
```

For global constants, the python style guide recommends ALL_CAPS. I recommend not using NS, instead spell it out NAMESPACE

```
def fast_iter(context, func,args=[],kwargs={}):
```

Taking variable arguments as a list and dict are odd, any reason you didn't take them as *args and **kwargs?

```
    # fast_iter is useful if we need to free memory while iterating through a
    # very large XML file.
    #http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
    # Author: Liza Daly

    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem,*args, **kwargs)
```

Using a yield to make this a generator rather then calling a function would probable be better.

```
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context
```

There is no point in deleting local names at the end of the function. When the function ends all the names will be deleted anyways.

```
def process_element(elt):
```

I recommend not using short abbreviations like elt unless they are really common.

```
    # global mzml_pk, sf_cv_fk,softw_fk_ID, softw_cv_fk_ID
    # Processing first element (mzML) and it's attributes (id, version, accession)
    # version attribute is required AND id & accession are optional
    if elt.tag==NS+taglist[0]:

        L= elt.keys()
        L1=['id','version','accession']

        # Checking whether element attributes (items L1) exist in a mzml element attributes (L)
        if L1[0] in L:
```

You haven't helped anything by storing 'id' L1[0] and then fetching it again. Just use 'id' here.

```
            mzmlID = elt.attrib['id']
        else:
            mzmlID = "-"
```

You should be able to do something like mzmlID = el.attrib.get('id', '-') to replace this whole if/else block.

```
        if L1[1] in L:
            mzml_version = elt.attrib['version']
        else:
            mzml_version = "-"
        if L1[2] in L:
            mzml_accession = elt.attrib['accession']
        else:
            mzml_accession = "-"

        exp_id_fk = exp_PK

        sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_mzml (mzml_id,accession,version,exp_id)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        try:
            # Execute the SQL command
            config.cursor.execute(sql,(mzmlID,mzml_accession,mzml_version,exp_id_fk))
            # Commit your changes in the database
            config.conn.commit()

            #mzml_pk= cursor.lastrowid
```

Don't leave dead code in comments

```
        except Exception as err:
            # logger.error(err)
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            config.conn.rollback()
```

Don't just ignore errors that happen. If you expect an error to occur, you should check to make sure exactly the error you wanted was caught. Otherwise you should re-raise or at least log the error.

You might also look into with statments and context managers. Amongst other things, they make transactions easier to work with.

```
        global mzml_pk
        mzml_pk = config.cursor.lastrowid
```

avoid use of global variables. Use return values/object attributes/pretty much anything before using a global variable.

```
    # Processing second element (sourceFile) which has attributes (id, name and location)
    # SourceFile attributes id, name and location are required
    # Further, sourceFile has child element (cvParam) and attributes (cvRef, name, accession, value)
    # cvParam attributes: cvRef, name, accession are Required and value optional
```

Right about now, this function is way too long. You should break it up into several functions.

```
    elif elt.tag==NS+taglist[1]:
        sf_keys = elt.keys()
        sf_need = ['id','name','location']
        if sf_need[0] in sf_keys:
            sf_id = elt.attrib['id']
        else:
            sf_id, "-"
        if sf_need[1] in sf_keys:
            sf_name = elt.attrib['name']
        else:
           sf_name, "-"
        if sf_need[2] in sf_keys:
            sf_location = elt.attrib['location']
        else:
            sf_location = "-"
        global sf_fk
        sf_fk = mzml_pk
        #print "Insert values into django sourceFile class data model"

        sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_source_file (sf_id,name,location,mzml_fk_id)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        try:
            # Execute the SQL command
            config.cursor.execute(sql,(sf_id,sf_name,sf_location,sf_fk))
            # Commit your changes in the database
            config.conn.commit()

        except Exception as err:
            # logger.error(err)
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            config.conn.rollback()
        #sf_pk = cursor.lastrowid
        global sf_cv_fk
        sf_cv_fk= config.cursor.lastrowid
```

Deja vu... You should see if you can refactor the simiairites between any two very similiar pieces of code like this.

```
        for child in elt.getchildren():
            sf_child_keys =child.keys()
            sf_child_need = ['cvRef','name','accession','value']

            if sf_child_need[0] in sf_child_keys:
                sf_cv_cvref = child.attrib['cvRef']
            else:
                sf_cv_cvref = "-"
            if sf_child_need[1] in sf_child_keys:
                sf_cv_name = child.attrib['name']
            else:
                sf_cv_name = "-"
            if sf_child_need[2] in sf_child_keys:
                sf_cv_accession = child.attrib['accession']
            else:
                sf_cv_accession = "-"
            if sf_child_need[3] in sf_child_keys :
                if len(child.get('value'))>0:
                    sf_cv_value =  child.attrib['value']
                else:
                    sf_cv_value = "-"
            else:
                sf_cv_value = "-"

            sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_source_file_cv (ref, accession,name,value,sf_fk_id)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
            try:
                # Execute the SQL command
                config.cursor.execute(sql,(sf_cv_cvref,sf_cv_accession,sf_cv_name,sf_cv_value,sf_cv_fk))
                # Commit your changes in the database
                config.conn.commit()
            except Exception as err:
                # logger.error(err)
                # Rollback in case there is any error
                config.conn.rollback()

# **Rest of the codes I have pasted because it's more then 300 lines but same concept reading other element**
```

You've got lots of repeating sections which is obnoxious to deal with. I'd try something like. You should pull any common elements into a function or perhaps but all the different elements in a big list/dictionary and pull data from there

```
def convert_bytes(bytes):
```

This function doesn't really convert bytes, it formats the count of bytes. The name could be better.

```
    bytes = float(bytes)
```

Why are you converting bytes to a float? I presume you don't have fractional bits

```
    if bytes >= 1099511627776:
        terabytes = bytes / 1099511627776
        size = '%.2fTB' % terabytes
    elif bytes >= 1073741824:
        gigabytes = bytes / 1073741824
        size = '%.2fGB' % gigabytes
    elif bytes >= 1048576:
        megabytes = bytes / 1048576
        size = '%.2fMB' % megabytes
    elif bytes >= 1024:
        kilobytes = bytes / 1024
        size = '%.2fKB' % kilobytes
    else:
        size = '%.2fb' % bytes
    return size
```

The code repeats the same idea several times, I'd use a data-based approach

```
UNITS = [ 
    (1024**4, 'TB'),
    (1024**3, 'GB'),
    (1024**2, 'MB'),
    (1024**1, 'KB'),
    (1024**0, 'b')
]

def convert_bytes(bytes):
    for size, unit in UNITS:
        if bytes > size:
           return '%d%s' % (bytes / size, unit)



def main():
    global EXP_PK
    # Start time counter
    begin=time.clock()

    # Reading file from the configured directory
    file_dir = r'D:\files\111102_CA2.mzML'
```

That's not a directory...

```
    # Reactor so it will read all new files from configured directory
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_dir)
```

Reactor? Did you mean refactor? Because that's not what that means either. Really, I can't heads or tails out of your comment

```
    # File name and extension
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    user= getpass.getuser()
    exp_name = name
    exp_type= ext[1:]
```

A comment explaining why you are stripping off the first character of the extension might be nice.

```
    exp_created_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(os.path.getctime(file_dir)))
    exp_modi_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(file_dir)))
    exp_uploaddate= datetime.date.today()
    exp_uptime = str(datetime.datetime.now())[10:19]
    exp_size = convert_bytes(os.path.getsize(file_dir))
    #exp_located = r'C:\Users\Thaman\Documents\My Dropbox\Files\small1.mzML'
    exp_located = r'C:\My Documents\Dropbox\Files\plgs_example.mzML'
    #exp_located =r'D:\files\111102_CA2.mzML'

    sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_experiment (user,filename,filetype,createddate,modifieddate,uploaddate,time,size,located)
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        config.cursor.execute(sql,(user,exp_name,exp_type,exp_created_time,exp_modi_time,exp_uploaddate,exp_uptime,exp_size,exp_located))
        # Commit your changes in the database
        config.conn.commit()
    except:
        #logger.error(err)
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        config.conn.rollback()
    global exp_PK
    exp_PK = config.cursor.lastrowid
```

You have this basic piece of code over and over again. That's a very big hint you should move it into a function and reuse it.

```
    #Reading elements from file
    for intag in range(len(taglist)):
```

Just use `for tag in taglist:` You aren't using the index, so there is no reason to use range

```
        context= etree.iterparse(file_dir,events=("end",),tag=NS+taglist[intag])
        fast_iter(context, process_element)

    tend= time.clock()
    print "\n\nTIME TAKEN TO COMPLETE JOB", tend-begin

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT**

You should do something like this in order to handle the different tag types. It'll be faster and clearer then what you are doing.

```
def process_foo_tag(element):
    fetch element from foo
    insert into database

def process_bar_tag(element):
    fetch elements for bar tag
    insert into database

TAGS = {
   'bar' : process_bar_tag,
   'foo' : process_foo_tag
}

def process_element(element):
    TAGS[element.tag](element)
```

Comment: Can you give me the hints in achieving parsing speed from above line of codes. I genuinely admire your review.

Comment: @thchand, for performance: don't commit after every statement. Commit at the end. Don't have a long chain of if-statements to decide what to do with a tag. Use a dictionary instead, have the keys be tag names and values functions to call.

Comment: Commit every statement? You mean query commit?

Comment: I mean every SQL statement. You don't need to commit for call to cursor.execute() just once at the end.

Comment: Is it good idea to set default list like i did for all needed tag and loop in context= etree.iterparse(file_dir,events=("end",),tag=NS+taglist[intag]). This is the one I have most doubt. I am trying to follow your tips regarding long chain of if-statement of deciding tag

Comment: I called cursor.execute() in every statement so element attributes value will be stored in database and get primary key which should be use in another table of database

Comment: @tchand calling cursor.execute() is correct. Calling conn.commit() for every cursor.execute() is incorrect. You should probably only call con.commit() once at the very end.

Comment: @tchand, if I understand you correctly, you should use a dictionary not a list. I'll add a little section to my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1726/discussion-between-thchand-and-winston-ewert)